# Counting first occurrence in Google Sheets with additional condition

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

**Description**

I have a table like this in Google Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cond1 | Person_code | n/a | Count | Cond2 | n/a | Result |
| __ | _______ | ________________ | _____ | ________ | _______ | _____ | ________ |
| 2 | 0 | Tom T_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 3 | 0 | Isrel I_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 4 | 1 | Patty P_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  | x |
| 5 | 1 | Isrel I_44767 |  | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 6 | 0 | Dummy D_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 7 | 1 | Patty P_447677 |  | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 8 | 1 | Jarson X_44768 |  | 1 | 1 |  | x |

A - Cond1       - either 0 or 1
B - Person_code - first name, second name and number which represents a date
C - n/a         - column not important for the case, included for the sake of numeration
D - Count       - either 0 or 1 because it counts THE first occurence of B with formula:

`COUNTIF($B$1:$B2;$B2)=1)+0` for row 2
`COUNTIF($B$1:$B3;$B3)=1)+0` for row 3 and so on.

NOTE: The important thing is to count ONLY THE FIRST occurence (see rows 4 and 7 for an example).

E - Cond2       - either 0 or 1
F - n/a         - column not important for the case, included for the sake of numeration
G - Result      - IF (Cond1 + Count + Cond 2 = 3) THEN x

**What the problem is**

Currently Column D counts the first occurence of B. It does not take into account anything else. Just the first occurence in B column. However, I need it to ignore (i.e. do not count) rows where Cond1 + Cond2 is different than 2 (i.e. 0 or 1). Instead, it should look for a first occurence of B where Cond1 + Cond2 = 2 and count it.

So the table should look like this (pay attention to D3, D5 and G5):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cond1 | Person_code | n/a | Count | Cond2 | n/a | Result |
| __ | _______ | ________________ | _____ | ________ | _______ | _____ | ________ |
| 2 | 0 | Tom T_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 3 | 0 | Isrel I_44767 |  | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 4 | 1 | Patty P_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  | x |
| 5 | 1 | Isrel I_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  | x |
| 6 | 0 | Dummy D_44767 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 7 | 1 | Patty P_447677 |  | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 8 | 1 | Jarson X_44768 |  | 1 | 1 |  | x |

Row 3 was ignored and the first occurence of 'Isrel I_44767' was found in row 5. Therefore an 'x' appeared in G in row 5.

I've tried to include additional conditions in D but can't get it to work. Any solution would be acceptable. It's okay to add additional columns, if needed or use a totally different approach.

I will be grateful for any advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need it to ignore (i.e. do not count) rows where Cond1 + Cond2 is different than 2 (i.e. 0 or 1). Instead, it should look for the first occurrence of B where Cond1 + Cond2 = 2 and count it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A8+E2:E8=2, 1, 0))
```

[image]

now to account for occurrences/instances eg. not count duplicates (if that's what you are after - it's not clear from your question):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(1=COUNTIFS(
 IF(A2:A10+E2:E10=2, B2:B10, ), 
 IF(A2:A10+E2:E10=2, B2:B10, ), 
 ROW(B2:B10), "<="&ROW(B2:B10)), 1, 0))
```

[image]

---

> G - Result - IF (Cond1 + Count + Cond 2 = 3) THEN x

and G2 would be:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A10+D2:D10+E2:E10=3, "x", ))
```

Comment: Yes, literally I do not need to count duplicates.